# write multiple values on single input

Tags: python-3.x, input

Following code converts numbers into letters, but I can only input one number at a time.

```
import string


def translate():
    d = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 0))
    message = d[int(input('Enter:'))]
    print(message)

translate()
```

example of what I'm trying to do:
Enter: 25345265
then it would output all numbers into their corresponding letters

Comment: How are you going to deal with the ambiguities in your number? Is `253` suppose to turn into `'cfd'` or `'zd'`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga not sure what the best way would be. Thought about creating a list out of it. Just using a comma would be the fastest i suppose. 2, 5, 3 ect... I should make an exception not to go over 25 too probably.

Comment: Or just spaces: "2 22 2 3 23"

Answer (score 0):

This could be your basic approach:

```
>>> import string
>>> d = {str(k):v for k,v in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)}
>>> message = input('Enter:')
Enter:2 5 3
>>> print("".join(d[x] for x in message.split()))
cfd
>>> message = input('Enter:')
Enter:25 3
>>> print("".join(d[x] for x in message.split()))
zd
>>> message = input('Enter:')
Enter:8 26 5 3
```

To deal with values outside of your range you can always either just not accept those number or deal with them with a default value like `'*'`

```
>>> message = input('Enter:')
Enter:8 26 5 25
>>> print("".join(d.get(x,'*') for x in message.split()))
i*fz
```